# I can't call my new variable, why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in rails, so I do not master even the subtleties of this langage.
I meet an error which say `undefined method 'prix' for Online::ActiveRecord_Associations` when I try to call my variable "prix" and "portion" into the post index. 
So I can I do that ?

My code :

Onlines controller :

```html
class OnlinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post 
  before_action :owned_online, only: [:new, :edit, :update]
  before_action :set_online

def index
  @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end 

  def new 
    @online = current_user.onlines.build
    @online.post_id = @post.id
    @online.user_id = current_user.id
  end 

  def create 
    @online = @post.onlines.create(online_params)
    @online.user_id = current_user.id
    @online.post_id = @post.id
    if @online.save(online_params)
       @online.update(push: true)
       @online.update(pushed_at: Time.zone.now)
      flash[:success] = 'Votre post est en ligne !'
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else 
      render 'new'
    end 
  end 

  def show 
    
  end 


def update  
    if @onlines.update(online_params)
      if @online.push == false
        if @online.portion <= 1
          @online.update(push: false)
          flash[:success] = 'Veuillez indiquer le nombre de parts disponibles '
          redirect_to root_path 
        else
         @online.update(push: true)
      
      flash[:success] = 'Votre post a bien été pushé !'
      redirect_to root_path      
      end   
    end
    else
      @user.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end


private 

def online_params
  params.require(:online).permit(:user_id, :post_id, :prix, :portion, :push, :pushed_at)
  end 

  def owned_online 
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to :back
  end
end  

  def set_post
  @post = Post.find_by(params[:post_id]) 
  end 


  def set_online
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @online = Online.find_by(params[:id]) 
  end 

end
```

Onlines/Index view :

```html
<div class="title text-center">
  <h1>Alors ? On mange quoi ?</h1>
</div>

<br>

<%= render 'posts/post' %>
```

posts /post view :

```html
<div class="row">
<%-@posts.each do |post|%>

<div class="post">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <h3> <%=post.title%></h3>
  </div>

  
 <p> Posted by : <%= link_to post.user.pseudo, profile_path(post.user.pseudo) %>,  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </p>


 
**<p><%= post.onlines.prix %></p>
<p><%= @online.portion %></p>**

  <div class="image text-center">
    <div class="image-border">
     <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium), class:'img-responsive'), post_path(post)%>
    </div>
  </div>



  </div> 
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

So, if you have any ideas, tell me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your posts/post.html.erb

```
**<p><%= post.onlines.prix %></p>
```

You encountered the error `undefined method 'prix' for Online::ActiveRecord_Associations` because `posts.onlines` is a collection of one or more `Online` objects, and NOT a single `Online` record.

By this, I meant that the following values may differ (as an example):

```
post.onlines.first.prix
post.onlines.last.prix
```

If you want to select just the `@online` record for every specific `post` in your `<%-@posts.each do |post|%>`
 loop, then you could just do the following

posts/post.html.erb

```
...
**<p><%= @online.prix %></p>
<p><%= @online.portion %></p>**
...
```

Or if you want to show all `prix` values for each `Online` record in `post.onlines`, then you could do the following

posts/post.html.erb

```
...
<% post.onlines.each do |online| %>
  **<p><%= online.prix %></p>
<% end %>
<p><%= @online.portion %></p>
...
```

Comment: @lilipupu no prob! :)